# Best way to set a state with ternary in SetState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state called " show saved". When someone clicks " show saved" I want " show saved" to change to " show hidden". Originally, it worked when I set state to change to " show hidden" onClick:

```
<p 
  onClick={changeTitle}
>
  {this.state.saved}
</p>
```

It called this function:

```
const changeTitle = () => {
  this.setState({ 
    saved:' show hidden' 
  })
}
```

But now i've added a ternary because I want it to change from " show saved" to " show hidden" back and forth, each time it's clicked. However, now it will not work. Why not?

```
this.setState({ 
  saved: saved === 'Show saved'? 'Show hidden': 'Show saved'
})
```

How can I fix? Essentially, when a user clicks the state jumps back and forth. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just do this outside of setState?

Comment: `this.state.saved === 'Show saved'` ?  Otherwise where have you defined a variable called `saved`?  Presumably there's an error on your browser console about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an updater function that takes the previous state as the first argument.

```js
this.setState(({saved}) => ({ saved: saved === 'Show saved'? 'Show hidden': 'Show saved'}));
```

Alternatively store a boolean value and calculate what to display based on that.

```js
this.setState(({saved})=>({saved: !saved}));
```

```html
<p onClick={changeTitle}>
{this.state.saved ? 'Show saved': 'Show hidden'}
</p>
```

Comment: I think the logic should be handled outside of setState somewhere in the function. I know you are answering ops question but still...

Comment: @otejiri I offered an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Functional](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b/) `setState` is the way to go when next state value depends on the previous one. It guarantees that the previous statee value you are using is always accurate.

```
this.setState((oldSaved) => ({ saved: oldSaved === 'Show saved'? 'Show hidden': 'Show saved'}))
```

Out of scope, but `boolean` is a better type to use for this. You can already see the problem you have when you use a `string` for this.

In one code snippet you have written `Show Hidden`, and in another `show hidden`. This type of bugs will arise and will become difficult to debug. Everywhere you check for this variable you will have to check for the exact correct string (probably use 2 extra variables to ensure that). That is why it is better to use a boolean flag and based on it being true or false, render the value and do other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing this:

```js
const changeTitle = () => {
      if (this.state.saved === 'Show saved') {
        this.setState({ saved: 'Hide saved' })
      } else {
        this.setState({ saved: 'Show saved' })
      }
```